# ¿Por qué cuando cargo una url por primera vez sin cache me arroja un internal server error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

estoy intentando detectar porque al cargar una url en modo incognito me arroja un internal server error. Cuando abro esa url mediante un botón en un landing page carga bien lo siguiente:
[image: Resultado de abrir la url mediante un botón en landing page]

Pero cuando intento cargar la url directo con la barra de direcciones en el navegador incognito por primera vez, me arroja lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La página está echa con angular y la ruta que carga eso es la siguiente:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'cars',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./modules/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
  }
];
```

Lo que me he percatado es que ni si quiera está cargando los scripts para poder montar el componente sino que directamente arroja el internal server error. Alguien sabe que podría estar produciendo ese error?. El sitio está montado en un servidor de azure y el backend esta echo en c#.

Comment: El problema como dice el mensaje "Internal Server Error" está en el servidor, ¿ya revisaste los logs en el servidor?

Comment: No puedes acceder a la ruta directa desde el navegador por que Angular no ha cargado, es decir hay una diferencia entre las rutas internas que maneja la aplicación Angular y las rutas del server donde esta alojada. El error que aparece es un error de servidor mas no de Angular, tienes que configurar tu servidor Azure para que mande el index.html y delegue el routing a Angular. Angular lo explica en su [documentación](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml), pero no tiene un ejemplo con Azure.

Comment: Voy a revisar esa documentación para implementar la regla de redirección y ver si funciona o si debo configurar algo en azure